# Java Character Array Errors

Tags: java, arrays, char, primitive

I'm making a method for translating characters into their corresponding numbers e.g. a=1, b=2 ...

I've been recieving flak from the IDE about my declaration of the dictionary array. I've read the documentation and still have no idea how I would improve this.

Thanks for all your responses in advance! :D

EDIT: Formatting

```
public static int charNumTrans(char toBeTranslated){
    //Variable init
    int translated = 0;
    char guessedVariable;

    //Checking if between a and i
    if(toBeTranslated == 'a' || toBeTranslated == 'b' || toBeTranslated == 'c' || toBeTranslated == 'd' || toBeTranslated == 'e' 
    || toBeTranslated == 'f' || toBeTranslated == 'g' || toBeTranslated == 'h' || toBeTranslated == 'i'){ //Checking to see which array to use

        char[] dictionary;
        dictionary = new char {'0','.','1','a','2','b','3','c','4','d','5','e','6','f','7','g','8','h','9','i'};

        //chekcing between j and s
    }else if(toBeTranslated == 'j' ||toBeTranslated == 'k' ||toBeTranslated == 'l' ||toBeTranslated == 'm' ||toBeTranslated == 'n' ||
             toBeTranslated == 'o' ||toBeTranslated == 'p' ||toBeTranslated == 'q' ||toBeTranslated == 'r' || toBeTranslated == 's'){//Checking to see if in between 
        dictionary[10] = {'0','j','1','k','2','l','3','m','4','n','5','o','6','p','7','q','8','r','9','s'};
    }else{//Everything else will be in this data set.
        char[] dictionary = {'0','t','1','u','2','v','3','w','4','x','5','y','6','z'};
    }

    guessedVariable = dictionary[1];
    while(dictionary[guessedVariable] != toBeTranslated){
        guessedVariable +=2;
        }

    // Assigns letter minus one of array. e.g. b = dictionary[5]. This will then assign dictionary[4] to translated.
    translated = Character.getNumericValue(dictionary[guessedVariable-1]); 
    return translated;
}
```

Comment: Your char[] dictionary is of block scope , how can it be accessible outside in while statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are not initializing your arrays outside of the if statements, meaning your code at the end won't be able to call the "dictionary" array. Second of all, the problem with using arrays in your scenario that you have different sized arrays. Third of all, in terms of how you are initializing the arrays, as people have pointed out, you need to create a new object that is correct for your data set e.g. `new char[] {...}`.

To fully solve your problem, you might want to consider something like this (I have initialized all of the arrays in the simplest way possible using the same method to avoid confusion):

```
public static int charNumTrans(char toBeTranslated){
    //Variable init
    int translated = 0;
    char guessedVariable;

    //Checking if between a and i
    if(toBeTranslated == 'a' || toBeTranslated == 'b' || toBeTranslated == 'c' || toBeTranslated == 'd' || toBeTranslated == 'e' 
|| toBeTranslated == 'f' || toBeTranslated == 'g' || toBeTranslated == 'h' || toBeTranslated == 'i'){ //Checking to see which array to use

        char[] dictionary = {'0','.','1','a','2','b','3','c','4','d','5','e','6','f','7','g','8','h','9','i'};
        return findValue(dictionary);

    //checking between j and s
    }else if(toBeTranslated == 'j' ||toBeTranslated == 'k' ||toBeTranslated == 'l' ||toBeTranslated == 'm' ||toBeTranslated == 'n' ||
         toBeTranslated == 'o' ||toBeTranslated == 'p' ||toBeTranslated == 'q' ||toBeTranslated == 'r' || toBeTranslated == 's'){//Checking to see if in between 

        char[] dictionary = {'0','j','1','k','2','l','3','m','4','n','5','o','6','p','7','q','8','r','9','s'};
        return findValue(dictionary);

    }else{//Everything else will be in this data set.

        char[] dictionary = {'0','t','1','u','2','v','3','w','4','x','5','y','6','z'};
        return findValue(dictionary);

    }

}

public static int findValue(char[] dictionary){
    guessedVariable = dictionary[1];
    while(dictionary[guessedVariable] != toBeTranslated){
         guessedVariable +=2;
    }

    // Assigns letter minus one of array. e.g. b = dictionary[5]. This will then assign dictionary[4] to translated.
    translated = Character.getNumericValue(dictionary[guessedVariable-1]); 
    return translated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
        dictionary = new char {'0','.','1','a','2','b','3','c','4','d','5','e','6','f','7','g','8','h','9','i'};

to

```
    dictionary = new char[] {'0','.','1','a','2','b','3','c','4','d','5','e','6','f','7','g','8','h','9','i'};
```

Answer (score 0):

For your array declaration, you are missing the `[]` when you assign the values to the array object you're creating - so, for example, change your declarations to this:

```
char[] dictionary = new char[]{'0','t','1','u','2','v','3','w','4','x','5','y','6','z'};
```

Also, if you are trying to convert letters to numerical equivalents, may I suggest that you cast the `char` that you've passed to the function into an `int`, and then subtract 61 from this value? 
Reason being is that 61 corresponds to the position of the character '*a*' on the Unicode character table, and would greatly simplify assigning a number to the letter that you pass in.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I was programming half C++ and half Java syntax.